# Apply regex on marked lines in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have thousands of xsl templates like this in a `xsl` file.

```
<xsl:template name="foo">
...
...
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="bar" > <!-- ending spaces after quote -->
...
...
</xsl:template>
```

My job is to add same namespaces here.
The changed xsl will look something like

```
    <xsl:template name="foo" xmlns="http://example.org">
    ...
    ...
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="bar" xmlns="http://example.org" > 
    ...
    ...
    </xsl:template>
```

This is my approach

**1.** mark all the line starting with `<xsl:template`

**2.** add regex on the marked line.

I am stuck with point 2. How can I apply some regex only on the marked line ?

Do you have any better approach to do ?

**Update**

My challenge is to replace all `>` with `xmlns="http://example.org">` only on the marked line.

Comment: Why not replace as plain text: `<xsl:template name="foo">` with `<xsl:template name="foo" xmlns="http://example.org">`?

Comment: That would be wise if I have one `foo` to change ? I need to handle `Bar` also. And there are many ..

Comment: OK, the task is clear now. What is the *problem*?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the question clears the task i believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to mark lines. Search for the whole value then replace at the appropriate place where required. Like this:

[image]

Here we are trying to find this:
`<xsl:template name="foo"`
and replace with:
`\1\2\3(\ )xmlns="http://example.org"`

Comment: It works like a charm. but with replace with regex `\1\2\3 xmlns="http://example.org"` not sure why (\) is required ?

Comment: `(\ )` was to add space. If `\1\2\3 xmlns="http://example.org"` is working then it is Ok.

Comment: The final cute regex will be replace `(<xsl:template name=.*")` with `\1 xmlns="http://example.org"`